# How to leave settings by mouse?

Tags: android, settings

I have an app that shall be completely usable by using a mouse (attached to USB OTG). Everthing works fine, except one thing: I can go into the app settings... but how to go out from there???

Here is the source I am using for settings - honestly I have no idea on how to add a "go back"/"leave" button here. Or is there another clever way to do this?

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity 
{
    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=11)
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
        else
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }


}
```

Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Maulik Sheth - your answer was 90 % of the solution. It was correct, but I did not manage to put that into a working solution yesterday. Now - for others having the same problem, here is my code that works for me.

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity 
{
    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
            ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case android.R.id.home:
                    getActivity().finish();
                    return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=11)
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
        else
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you add **up button** at your settings actionbar ? or if you are not using action bar then check if its possible to include any header xml that has an imagebutton so that you can create an intent and go back?

i use this for action bar sherlock

> ActionBar ab;
>
> ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

and use it as

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        //create intent
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is, that I connot use finish() in preferences and also setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled does not work in preferences screen.

Comment: are you sure about this? i just checked the GMAIL app's settings has this up button and can navigate back. check for yourself! it does :)

Comment: You are right. I have just checked... GMAIL app can do exactly what I need. Now... if you can tell me HOW, you are my hero of the day. :-)

Comment: question: do you use actionbar in your app??...

i have not yet worked with preference but are you sure you cant set up button on action bar for preferences? if not with the default android's actionbar try using actionbar sherlock